# AltBeacon setBeaconLayout()

Tags: android, altbeacon

I would like to know what the Beacon Code stands for.
I mean, as far as I know it should identify the beacon layout.
Does this mean that I can customize any sort of layout and assign to it any sort of Beacon Code?
I mean, can I write something like that:

setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=abcd,i:4-13,i:14-23,p:24-24,d:25-25")?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 38):

According to [AltBeacon docs](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/index.html?org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconParser.html):

> m - matching byte sequence for this beacon type to parse (exactly one
> required)
>
> s - ServiceUuid for this beacon type to parse (optional, only for
> Gatt-based beacons)
>
> i - identifier (at least one required, multiple allowed)
>
> p - power calibration field (exactly one required)
>
> d - data field (optional, multiple allowed)
>
> x - extra layout.  Signifies that the layout is secondary to a primary
> layout with the same matching byte sequence (or ServiceUuid).  Extra
> layouts do not require power or identifier fields and create Beacon
> objects without identifiers.
>
> Example of a parser string for AltBeacon:
>
> "m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"
>
> This signifies that the beacon type will be decoded when an
> advertisement is found with 0xbeac in bytes 2-3, and a three-part
> identifier will be pulled out of bytes 4-19, bytes 20-21 and bytes
> 22-23, respectively. A signed power calibration value will be pulled
> out of byte 24, and a data field will be pulled out of byte 25.

here is a [list](https://beaconlayout.wordpress.com/) of some beacon layouts

```
ALTBEACON      m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
EDDYSTONE TLM  x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15
EDDYSTONE UID  s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19
EDDYSTONE URL  s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v
IBEACON        m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i make custom beacon layout for
0x229abaf03ed601010201000000000000
as its a eddystone beacon. i just want to search for this beacon using altbeacon library/